# VUE component mutual interference

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component named "MText",
I insert the component twice,like this:

`<MText></MText>`

`<MText></MText>`

"MText" bind a click event to remove itself through "this.$el.remove();",but I click the second one,it is strange that the first one is removed;why?thanks everyone who can help me~~thx very much!

Comment: try adding a unique key to each component `<MText :key="1"></MText> <MText :key="2"></MText>`. This helps with virtual DOM diffing

Comment: Post more of your code.